# Slow scrollbar in FullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

I have a little issue with FullPage.js.

I made `scrollOverflow: true`, and on Windows everything is alright. But on BlackBerry browser or **Android** browser this scroll is very... hm... heavy and slowly.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already being treated in fullpage.js issues in [this topic](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/506).

No solution has been implemented yet.